# Azure P6 managed disk selection

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disk

As a part of free tier we can get 2*P6 SSDs disk for free , but when I am trying to create VM , i can't get option to select disk type as P6. Can any one please help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means you need to use any VM sku that has `S` in its name. Premium disks only work with those.